# ¿Cómo agregar un Listen a TextView?

Tags: android

Lo que busco es que mientras esté el foco en el TextView se pueda verificar si está vacío o tiene al menos algo, para que así pueda ocultar o mostrar según sea el caso, un textView.

Porque tengo la idea que con un OnClickListener, pero no sé si eso me puede ayudar a verificar en tiempo real cuando el EditText esté vacío cuando se encuentre activo el foco en él.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola Ramses, tu pregunta debe referirse únicamente a EditText o me equivoco :|

Comment: sí, cuando empiece a editar el campo de EditText que realice dos acciones dependiendo el caso: Si el campo del EditText tiene texto entonces el TextView aparecería, y en caso contrario, si el campo del EditText está vacío entocnes el TextViewdesaparecería.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como comentas tienes que agregar un listener en este caso **[OnFocusChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnFocusChangeListener.html)** :

```
    EditText editText = (EditText ) findViewById(R.id.my_editText);

    editText.setOnFocusChangeListener (new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus){  //El EditText esta enfocado!
                //Comprobación para revisar si contiene texto:
                if(((EditText)v).getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()," No contiene texto." ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()," Contiene texto, el texto es: " + ((EditText)v).getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]